# SelectableText in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

SelectableText does not work correctly when I try to select it and scroll in page.
Here is my code and I want to correct it so that it works correctly when I select it and scroll:

```
class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationMenu(),
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Page 2")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SelectableText('''
              Some long text
               Example row 1\n
               Example row 2\n
               Example row 3\n
               Example row 4\n
               Example row 5\n
               Example row 6\n
               Example row 7\n
               Example row 8\n
               Example row 9\n
               Example row 10\n
               Example row 11\n
               ''',
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

I tried to select the text and scroll with the selection, but when I scroll, the screen returns to a point further back.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first step you should do is wrap the SingleChildScrollView with
   Gesturedetector.
2. Then you should make 3 methods that would handle the following :

- Handle the drag start
- Handle the drag update
- Handle the scroll to the latest position

[image]
Here is somewhat the code that you can create , edit it accordingly
also declare in the beginning :

Offset startPosition;

double startScrollPosition;

For learning you check these links it would make u more clear:

```
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragStartDetails-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html
```